# need help to create following motion

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to create following motion using moveTo or MoveBy methods of cocos2d[image]

when I touch object should move there.Is it possible in cocos2d?

Answer (score 0):

- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

  for( UITouch *touch in touches ) {

  ```
  CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

  location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];
  ```

//while creating sprite set like sprite.tag=2;

```
            CCSprite *spr=[self getChildByTag:2];//use your sprite tag while creating


    id move = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:4 position:location];

            [spr runAction:move];
```

Comment: please see its not purely linear motion its some how projectile

Comment: sorry.i cant understand ur pictures

Comment: see after the blue color object slightly changes it direction

Comment: ok.see I have a ball which i want to move in starting its on ground .when I touch on any location at top it moves there but when it passes from blue color it slightly changes its direction